# Windows 8 Metro App Offline Mode

Tags: visual-studio-2013, offline

I need to test how an app behaves while offline. Is there a way to simulate an app being offline when lauched from Visual Studio?

---

I am looking for something besides the obvious like unplugging the cable. In iOS and adroid there is a setting but I can't find something similar on Windows 8/Visual Studio.

Comment: Unplug your network cable?

Comment: @TheBlueDog I am looking for an alternative to that.